# AppsScript to match ID's and write value to cell when match is found

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a project in which I have two sheets, 'staging' and 'export' with cells that contain a unique ID. When I set the value in Column A of 'staging' to "export", that row of data is included on the sheet 'export'. I have a script on the export sheet that when run, exports the data to a csv file and sends it to a google drive folder. It also copies the set of exported data to another sheet named 'exported' as an archive of exported records. What I want the script to also do is loop through the id's of both the 'staging' and 'export' rows, find the id's that match, and when the match is found, change the value in column A of 'staging' to "Complete", which removes it from the export tab.

I am unsure how to write the loop and if statement to toggle the status column on the 'staging' sheet. Here is my code so far:

```
//this script will toggle the export? column on staging to 'complete'
//after the export script completes


function toggleComplete(){

//get the ID's on the 'staging' tab

const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

const staging = ss.getSheetByName('staging');
const stagingIDRange = staging.getRange(2,4,staging.getLastRow(),1).getValues();
const statusRange = staging.getRange("A2:A");
console.log(stagingIDRange);

//get the ID's on the 'toexport' tab

const exportsheet = ss.getSheetByName('toexport');
const toExportIDRange = exportsheet.getRange(2,8,exportsheet.getLastRow(),1).getValues();
console.log(toExportIDRange);

//match to the id in column H of the toexport tab

//if (stagingIDRange = toExportIDRange)
//get row number of matching ID's 
//use row number to toggle the matching rows
//if the ids's match then toggle column A on staging for that row to complete

//statusRange.setValue('Complete');



}
```

Any help would be appreciated. [Here is a link to make a copy of the sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XtdPk93z_gSBWdJpv8x3cAf6-QCAQ69a2x7j8Net0aQ/copy) that I am working on. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XtdPk93z_gSBWdJpv8x3cAf6-QCAQ69a2x7j8Net0aQ/copy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An approach you can try is to get the 1D array equivalent of both ID columns for easier comparison.

Once you got them, traverse the staging IDs and then by using `includes`, you can check if a staging ID is present in the toExport IDs array.

#### Code:

```
function toggleComplete(){
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  //get the ID's on the 'staging' tab
  const staging = ss.getSheetByName('staging');
  const stagingIDRange = staging.getRange(2,4,staging.getLastRow() - 1,1).getValues();
  const stagingIDs = stagingIDRange.flat().filter(String);

  //get the ID's on the 'toexport' tab
  const exportsheet = ss.getSheetByName('toexport');
  const toExportIDRange = exportsheet.getRange(2,8,exportsheet.getLastRow() - 1,1).getValues();
  const toExportIDs = toExportIDRange.flat().filter(String);

  stagingIDs.forEach(function (stagingID, index){
    if(toExportIDs.includes(stagingID))
      // properly offset the row parameter
      staging.getRange(index + 2, 1).setValue("COMPLETE");
  });
}
```

#### Note:

- `flat` transforms your multilevel array into a 1D array
- `filter(String)` filters your data and remove non-string elements (thus removes blank elements in your array)
- `includes` checks if a value is an element of an array

#### Output:

[image: output]